# Controller scope across scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html structure

```
 <div kendo-splitter k-orientation="'horizontal'" k-panes='[{ collapsible: true, size: "15%" }
                                                    , { collapsible: false }
                                                    , { collapsible: true, size: "15%" }]' style="position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 0%; height: 80%; width: 100%">
            <div>Incident</div>
            <div ng-controller="layoutController">
                Video
                <nv-layout id="nv-layout" layout-entries="layoutEntries" on-selected="onSlotSelected" on-resize="onLayoutResized"></nv-layout>
            </div>
            <div>Sensors</div>
        </div>
```

nv-layout directive is defined as

```
 var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            layoutEntries: "=",
            selected: "&onSelected",
            resized: "&onResized"
        },
        template: "<div></div>"
    };
```

I want to put the controller in the splitter div so it will be able to listen to the resize events, how ever when i did it the layoutEntries binding broke, is there a limitation to where i can add the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is easiest when you stick to custom directives. If you would like I could provide an example.

To answer your question "is there a limitation to where I can add the controller?"

Yes, it must be above the code you wish to control. In your example, you have Angular code above and below your controller. However, you can nest controllers. Something like...

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div kendo-splitter k-orientation="'horizontal'" k-panes='[{ collapsible: true, size: "15%" }
                                                , { collapsible: false }
                                                , { collapsible: true, size: "15%" }]' style="position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 0%; height: 80%; width: 100%">
        <div>Incident</div>
        <div ng-controller="layoutController">
            Video
            <nv-layout id="nv-layout" layout-entries="layoutEntries" on-selected="onSlotSelected" on-resize="onLayoutResized"></nv-layout>
        </div>
        <div>Sensors</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your js files

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.blah = 'blah'
});

app.controller('layoutController',function($scope){
  $scope.blah = 'blah'
});
```

Plus, you may want to follow an Angularjs style guide and label your controllers in UppderCamelCase.

Here is a link:

[A Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide)